# SASS BEM Wildcards

Tags: html, sass, wildcard, bem

I've been using BEM (a modified version of it at least) for quite some time; and have recently switched over from writing CSS to Sass it seems to lend itself to BEM quite nicely, but I can't figure out how to easily wild-card specificity.

For instance; let's say I have a few buttons:

```html
<button
  class="BLOCK__ELEMENT BLOCK__ELEMENT--MODIFIER1"
>
  Click Me 1
</button>

<button
  class="BLOCK__ELEMENT BLOCK__ELEMENT--MODIFIER2"
>
  Click Me 2
</button>

<button
  class="BLOCK__ELEMENT BLOCK__ELEMENT--MODIFIER3"
>
  Click Me 3
</button>
```

In a CSS file I could write the following:

```css
.BLOCK__ELEMENT {
  border-radius: 2rem
}

.BLOCK_ELEMENT--MODIFIER1 {
  background-color: red
}

.BLOCK_ELEMENT--MODIFIER2 {
  background-color: white
}

.BLOCK_ELEMENT--MODIFIER3 {
  background-color: blue
}
```

and all would be right in the world

in Sass I Could simplify that as follows:

```css
.BLOCK__ELEMENT {
  border-radius: 2rem

  &--MODIFIER1 {
    background-color: red
  }

  &--MODIFIER2 {
    background-color: white
  }

  &--MODIFIER3 {
    background-color: blue
  }
}
```

Which is a nice improvement

---

**But what I'd really like to do is simplify my markup as follows**

```html
<button
  class="BLOCK__ELEMENT--MODIFIER1"
>
  Click Me 1
</button>

<button
  class="BLOCK__ELEMENT--MODIFIER2"
>
  Click Me 2
</button>

<button
  class="BLOCK__ELEMENT--MODIFIER3"
>
  Click Me 3
</button>
```

and have Sass that looks something like this:

```css
.BLOCK__ELEMENT {

  &* {
    border-radius: 2rem
  }

  &--MODIFIER1 {
    background-color: red
  }

  &--MODIFIER2 {
    background-color: white
  }

  &--MODIFIER3 {
    background-color: blue
  }
}
```

Is there any such wildcard implementation in sass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another possible solution

```css
@use "sass:string"

@mixin self() {
  $self: string.slice(#{&}, 2);
  
  @at-root &, [class*="#{$self}"] {
    @content
  }
}
```

```css
.Block {
  @include self() {
    border-radius: 2rem;
  }

  &--modifier1 {
    background-color: red;
  }
  &--modifier2 {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  &--modifier1 {
    background-color: salmon;
  }

  &__element {
    @include self() {
      width: 50px;
    }

    &--modifier {
      background-color: skyblue;
    }

  }
}
```

And this is compiled this way

```css
.Block, [class*=Block] {
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.Block--modifier1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.Block--modifier2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.Block--modifier1 {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.Block__element, [class*=Block__element] {
  width: 50px;
}

.Block__element--modifier {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome; thanks! This'll clean up my HTML tremendously! I can get a little compulsive with my classes, often adding a class that looks like this: `BLOCK BLOCK__ELEMENT BLOCK__ELEMENT--MODIFIER` so that I can style things consistently -- but I've hated the overhead in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

how about good old css? :)

```
[class*="BLOCK__ELEMENT-"]
```

Comment: I played with that; and it works -- I was hoping there was a nested wildcard implementation I could you in scss -- for organizational purposes

I'll have to check and see if
`[class*=&]` would work -- it isn't pretty, but that'd do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Like say Sueno, you can use [class*="BLOCK__ELEMENT--"] and do this:

```
.BLOCK_ELEMENT {

  @at-root &, [class*="BLOCK_ELEMENT"] { // or just @at-root [class*="BLOCK_ELEMENT"]
    border-radius: 2rem;
  }

  &--MODIFIER1 {
    background-color: red
  }

  &--MODIFIER2 {
    background-color: white
  }

  &--MODIFIER3 {
    background-color: blue
  }  
}
```

Comment: This works, so thank you for that, but I'm really hoping there's something that uses a reference like `[class*=&]`

If you nest this deeper, using ```
.Block {
  &_ELEMENT {
    border-radius: 2rem;
    &--MODIFIER1 {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

It'd be ideal to use something like `[class*=&]` in the block to represent the block and again in the element to represent the element

What I'm looking for may just not be possible (syntax wise), but your response does provide a working solution (I just didn't want to redundantly write the block or block_element)

Comment: I'm going to leave this open for a little while longer to see if you or anyone else has a method to reduce the duplication, but if not I'll accept this and close it out -- thanks for taking the time; cheers